# SailsJS: Data Column Type for `boolean` always showing warning about "transforming" column name back to attribute

Tags: types, boolean, sails.js

Here is the screenshot for reference using `boolean` as type in SailsJs WaterLine
[Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e38WY.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! **[We discourage screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)**. You are making it harder to help you because we have to retype your data or code 

Comment: @ChristopheHubert ``` isCancel: { type: 'ref', columnName: 'CANCELLED', columnType: 'boolean', defaultsTo: false }, ``` I try to use this as a work-around and the warn just disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you provided does reveal the reason for the warning. It looks like the actual data in the database is different from the model definition. This could happen when migrating information from the one type of database that represents boolean as 1 and 0 (MySQL for example) to something that does not (Postgres or MongoDB ? ). This also happens when editing the data in the database from somewhere else (MySQL Workbench, PGAdmin or another non Waterline code) and not being careful about the types. Waterline ORM can get confused in that case and this is the reason for the warning.

All above is described in the warning message.

Another reason might be if somewhere in the code you modify or plain provide wrong data to the ORM when saving/editing information. Providing 1 and 0 instead of true or false can cause this warning. Common places for this to happen are in `api/controllers` or `api/models` in lifecycle callbacks.

You can start by checking your data and database for any inconsistencies and fixing them. And then scanning your controllers and models for any suspicious code.

Comment: ```
    isCancel: {
      type: 'ref',
      columnName: 'CANCELLED',
      columnType: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false
    },
```
I try to use this as a work-around and the warn just disappear. Thank for your help also.